# Fonts in iOS Calculator app

Tags: xcode, uikit, ios10, uifont

What fonts does iOS calculator app uses in +, -, x, divide? I tried System Thin font of size 40 but it doesn't work no matter what UIFont I choose. Or they are custom images? Is it possible to reuse them in our own iOS app?

Comment: No, you cannot use assets from other apps in your app. Even if you could get them somehow, you don't have the proper rights to use those images.

Comment: My question is whether they can not be reproduced using any of the system fonts?

Comment: Haven't tried it, but maybe this helps: https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/